# Remove backPressed event listeners in trigger.io

Tags: android, events, back-button, trigger.io

Is it somehow possible to remove android back button event listeners added by forge.event.backPressed.addListener in trigger.io? As far as I know, there are no API methods for that. So is it possible to do it without that or is that a no go for now?

Comment: No Trigger.io API for this yet. You'll have to handle that on your own with a custom solution (e.g. have one actual backPressed listener and subscribe/unsubscribe with your own additional methods).

Comment: That approach worked. Thanks Patrick!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try onBackPressed() ?

```
  @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        //super.onBackPressed();
        if(SOME_CONDITION_TO_CHECK){
            //THIS BLOCK WILL NOT DO ANYTHING AND WOULD DISABLE BACK BUTTON

        }else{
            super.onBackPressed();
        //THIS BLOCK WILL BE CALLED IF ABOVE COND IS FALSE, AND WOULD ENABLE BACK BUTTON
        }

    }
```

Comment: I'd rather avoid tampering with trigger's source. Might consider as last resort though.